# angular-cesium open 4 maps simultaneously

Tags: angular, maps, cesiumjs

We have a project written in angular 7 + angular cesium as map infrastructure, The app is running on local PC's.

A new request demands that we will be able to open 4 different maps with many entities over each angular cesium layer.

We are struggling with the documentation of angular cesium, and facing difficulties on getting good performance with even one map that contains many entities on top of it, therefore I was wondering if there is a best practice for using multiple maps as described above.

Many thanks.

Comment: welcome to SO! please follow this rules to ask your question properly: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Could not simply comment so i'll put this here...

what about this  chind of use:

https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/Sandcastle/?src=Multiple%20Synced%20Views.html&label=Beginner

instead of using a widget for everymap you split the view of a single widget in 4 it costs less resurces.